# Extract month and year from Postgres DB

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in my Postgres DB:

MY_TABLE

```
date_col  |id_col
----------+---------
2017-12-28|892800126
2018-01-03|892814475
2018-01-03|892803143
2018-01-03|892803710
2018-01-03|892813971
2018-01-03|892803143
2018-01-03|892804791
```

I need to create a new column with year, month and day in each one from  'date' column. How do I do that?
I have been trying in this way:

```
select date_col, id_col
extract(year from date_col) as ano,
extract(month from id_col) as mes
from MY_TABLE;
```

I have been trying in a bunch of ways, but I received the message
"SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "extract". Position: 28"

Please, someone help me.

Comment: What is the datatype of the "date" column? What does "creating a new column year month day in each one mean"? Do you mean "create new *columns*"?

Comment: How would you get a month from `892800126`? did you mean `extract(month from date_col) as mes`?

Comment: Hi, Bohemian. Yes, I mean "create new columns" and "extract(month from date_col) as mes". Sorry.

Comment: I hope by create a new column you actually mean generate a column in the result set. Not a new column in the table. That would jest be duplicating data and subject to consistency  errors.  But either way your syntax error is a missing comma (,) between id_col and extract.

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `id_col`

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

```
select date_col,id_col,
extract (year from date_col) as m_year,
extract (month from date_col) as m_month , 
extract (day from date_col) as m_day 
from MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: I received: "SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) does not exist. Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."